# How it's possible decide CNF by having a turing machine that decide SAT?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

Suppose we have a Turing machine $M$ as black box that decide $SAT$ problem. Now suppse we have a $CNF$ formula $\phi$ with $n$ variables. How it possible checking satisfiblity of $\phi$ and then finding that assignment with at most $2n+1$ times using $M$?

I know that every $SAT$ instance can comverted to $CNF$ clauses so i think we can do it recursively to checking satisfiblity and then finding it, but i get stuck to formulate it that how we can do it.

Also similar question asked at this [link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/is-there-a-non-deterministic-linear-time-algorithm-for-cnf-sat).

Comment: The SAT problem is defined as the problem of deciding whether a boolean formula (usually in conjunctive normal form) is satisfiable. So why can't you just invoke $M$ once on your input CNF formula?

Comment: It's also ambiguous for me, look at exercise 3.1 section a from the following link https://archive.model.in.tum.de/um/courses/complexity/SS10/exercises/ex03.pdf

Comment: My question come from that link.

Comment: The question is not asking to just decide whether $\phi$ is satisfiable. It is asking **to compute a satisfying assignment**.

Comment: Thank you, so how it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decide whether a CNF formula is satisfiable or not you can simply decide it with one invoke of $M$ on your formula.
But if you want to calculate its satisfying assignment, your problem is a search problem not a decision problem. To do that you can simply invoke $M$ on $\phi [True/x_i]$ (substituting variable $x_i$ with value $True$) for each variable $x_i$ recursively until no more variables left. It is easy to see that if the result is $Accept$, you can assign $True$ to $x_i$ and $False$ otherwise and recurse on the new formula $\psi= \phi [v(x_i)/x_i]$. If you want more details about how to formulate it you can check Arrora complexity book for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check whether $\phi$ is satisfiable using $M$. If it is, you can find a satysying assignment as follows:

For each variable $x$ of $\phi$ do the following:

- Set $x$ to true. Simplify $\phi$ to remove $x$ (if a clause contains $x$ then you can delete the clause, if a clause contains $\overline{x}$ then you can delete $\overline{x}$ from the clause) and let $\phi_x$ be the resulting formula.
- Check whether $\phi_x$ is satisfiable using $M$.
- If $\phi_x$ is satisfiable, set $\phi=\phi_x$ and continue with the next variable.
- Otherwise $x$ must be false. Set $x$ to false and update by $\phi$ by removing all occurrences of $x$ or $\overline{x}$ (if a clause contains $\overline{x}$ then you can delete the clause, if a clause contains $x$ then you can delete $x$ from the clause). Then continue with the next variable.

At the end of this process, the values assigned to the variables are a satisfying assignment of the input formula. This requires at most $n+1$ invocations of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it in at most $n+1$ queries. Just first check that the whole sentence is satisfiable, then play guess-and-check for each variable. Writing $|\phi|$ for the number of variables in the sentence $\phi$,

$$\mathit{cnf\_and\_sat}(\phi)=\left\{\begin{align*}
&\mathit{cnf}(\phi,|\phi|)&\mathit{sat}(\phi)\\
&\mathbf{unsat}&\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{align*}\right.$$

$$\mathit{cnf}(\phi,n)=\left\{\begin{align*}
&\emptyset&n=0\\
&\{x_n\}\cup\mathit{cnf}(\phi\land x_n,n-1)&n\ne0\enspace\mathrm{and}\enspace\mathit{sat}(\phi\land x_n)\\
&\{\overline{x_n}\}\cup\mathit{cnf}(\phi\land\overline{x_n},n-1)&\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{align*}\right.$$